# Far manager for linux?

Tags: linux

I've been using [far manager](http://www.farmanager.com) under windows for about the last 6 years, and can't find anything like it for linux. mc is not a reasonable replacement, and gnome commander is not either. Are there any [OFM](http://www.softpanorama.org/OFM/index.shtml) veterans out there that can point me in the right direction for linux?

Comment: https://github.com/elfmz/far2l

Answer (score 9):

[Midnight Commander](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) (mc) is the usual answer, but there are others.

I'd recommend you take a look at [GNU Interactive Tools](http://www.gnu.org/s/gnuit/), or GNUit (it was *git* before Linus "reappropriated" the name...) Like other GNU tools, it has [EMACS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)-like bindings throughout.

GNUit is console-based and extensible, and has the dual-pane file manager layout with a command line underneath with editing and memory. You might like it.

Comment: I'll check it out, I'm a vim guy at heart, but if the normal (scp, editable keybindings, the ability to use whatever editor I want when I hit f4...) stuff works then it might be just what I'm looking for. mc really bites, I don't know how people can use it without getting frustrated and dropping into straight bash.

Comment: I'm a vim guy too - but using vi-mode in bash just never works completely right. I use ksh any time I can help it.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Krusader](http://www.krusader.org/). The only disadvantage of it is graphical interface. So it will be difficult (but possible `*`) to use it remotely.

`*` Do you know about X11 forwarding? It gives you ability to run at server GUI applications and work with their GUI locally. All interaction with user and windows is translated through network. Usually one uses `ssh` with -X switch for it.

Answer (score 1):

There was an attempt to port FAR to Linux called "[farsh](http://sourceforge.net/projects/farsh/)" but it died before any code got written :))

Answer (score 0):

The usual (at least for me) way to handle such things is to get a VNC window over an ssh tunnel, and thereby use a full fledged desktop environment of my choise, be that GNOME, KDE, or any other. Something similar works on windows with RDP protocol (Remote Desktop). I believe the existence of these options make any Norton Commander clone obsolete.

The method of doing this of course depends on your client system. What I do on Windows is:

- I have vncserver installed on my server
- I use putty to provide the ssh tunnel
- I use TightVNC as the vnc client on my end.

I'm sure googling these terms will provide a lot of how-to's.